# How can I skip a section with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout's section provider?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm building a new screen in my app using [UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout). I have different layouts per-section, so I'm using the [section provider initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout/3199214-initwithsectionprovider).

I'd like to be able to hide and show some sections based on the layout environment passed to the provider. I was somehow under the impression that I could do this by simply returning a `nil` section - the return type is nullable - but when I return a nil section I get an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid section definition. Please specify a valid section definition when content is to be rendered for a section. This is a client error.'
>
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> CoreSimulator 757.3 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro (C26C7431-8081-43CB-8E77-F79C8B8B3924) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro

What is the best way to skip a section here? And why is the return type of the section provider nullable if returning null throws an exception?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to skip a section here?

You could return zero as the number of cells in the hidden section.

There's no magic formula otherwise. You would just have to reduce your numbering, taking account of what's being displayed.

For example, if there are 5 sections, they are sections 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Now suppose you don't want section 2 to be displayed. Now there are 4 sections (the value for the number of sections has changed), and they are sections 0, 1, 2, and 3.

The difference is that when there are just 4 sections, section 2 is laid out like section 3 was laid out previously, and section 3 is laid out like section 4 was laid out previously.